# Assign custom ParameterEncoding per viewcontroller for Alamofire Request

Tags: ios, json, swift, encoding, alamofire

**UPDATED Question:**

At first my issue was about assigning a custom `ParameterEncoding` per `ViewController` based on the `HTTP.Method` request, I found a solution and added the string in the `Alamofire.request` then added `import Alamofire` to the head of each `ViewController` which helped calling `JSONEncoding` and `URLEncoding` and changed the way of call by adding the header to the request as well to avoid 401 unauthorized error.

```
func callingHttpRequest(params:Dictionary<String,Any>, apiname:String,cuurentView:UIViewController,method:HTTPMethod, taskCallback: @escaping (Int,
    AnyObject?) -> Void)  {

    let urlString  = HOST_NAME + apiname

    print("url",urlString)
    print("params", params)
    Alamofire.request(urlString,method: method,parameters:params).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let resultData):
            taskCallback(1,resultData as AnyObject)
            let returnData = String(data: response.data! , encoding: .utf8)
            print("returnData" ,returnData!)
            print("request URL", response.request!)
            break
        case .failure(let error):

             let returnData = String(data: response.data! , encoding: .utf8)
             print("returnData" ,returnData!)
            print("request URL", response.request!)

            if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet(){
                NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                cuurentView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                let AC = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                })
                let noBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                })
                AC.addAction(okBtn)
                AC.addAction(noBtn)
                cuurentView.present(AC, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
            }
            else{
                let errorCode:Int = error._code;
                if errorCode != -999 && errorCode != -1005{
                    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                    cuurentView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    let AC = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                        taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                    })
                    let noBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    })
                    AC.addAction(okBtn)
                    AC.addAction(noBtn)


                    cuurentView.present(AC, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
               }else if errorCode == -1005{
                   NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                   taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                }

            }
            break;

        }


    }
```

Now what's really pissing me off is the response of the request, the app is made with user login so each time the app runs it will check if the user logged in or not. When the HTTP request is sent the response returns with `SQL Query` added to `JSON` if the user is logged in as below

Failure returnData string(84) "SELECT * FROM customer where LOWER(user) = 'helloworld' AND status = '1'"
{"success":true,"data":[{,,,,,"}

This is causing a failure response and and error

> Warning: JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.

This is really insane why the response is returning a `SQL Query` while it shouldn't. That wasn't happening before I customized the header and encoding of the `Alamofire.request`.

Any way faced such issue can hep please!

**P.S.:** The response has 200 OK HTTP Response but with failure Data Response

Comment: Your code seems to be okay to me Try to clean the project or restart the xcode

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya please check my edit question version. I have an issue getting 401 error reply back from server